# Find first image from folder

Tags: php

I am using below code successfully to find the first image from a folder and display it. The problem I have is that the client has uploaded images with a mixture of uppercase and lowercase .jpg extensions on the images. Can i adjust my code to allow for both uppercase and lowercase .jpg extensions, as it only likes lower case?

```
$search_dir = "properties/".$row['Reference_No'];
    $images = glob("$search_dir/*.jpg");
    sort($images);

    // Image selection and display:

    //display first image
    if (count($images) > 0) { // make sure at least one image exists
        $img = $images[0]; // first image
        echo "<img src='../../$img' width='320' height='200' border='0' /> ";
    } else {
        // possibly display a placeholder image?
    }
```

Comment: you mean like this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.natcasesort.php look at the first example

Comment: check this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)

Comment: On top of that JPEG files are not bound to having the extension `.jpg` only - it could also be `.jpe`, `.jpeg` and `.jfif`.

Answer (score 1):

You could merge your glob arrays

```
$images = array_merge(glob("$search_dir/*.jpg"),glob("$search_dir/*.JPG"));
```

As a side note; if you're handling the uploading of files, it might be an idea to [`strtolower()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php) them when storing, this way you wont have issues and "untidiness"

Answer (score 0):

Or

```
$images = glob("$search_dir/*.[jJ][pP][gG]");
```

But I do not understand well the concept of first image - sort() alphabetically !?